# Flutter: How can I get my array data in firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get my data in firestore wherein that data is array and output that data in a card. As of now the output I'm getting is "null". What is the best way to get this array of data? I'm using `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` to get the data.

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: db.collection('ACTIVITIES').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(
                        children: snapshot.data.documents
                            .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
                            .toList());
                  } else {
                    return SizedBox();
                  }
                })
```

Here is where I try to output the data:

```
Card buildItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
return Card(
  elevation: 5,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Name: ${doc.data['Name_ofUser']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Text(
          'Description: ${doc.data['Help_Description']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              color: Color(0xFF121A21),
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Respond',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Color(0xFF121A21),
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Read',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

This is my database structure:

[image: My db link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ACTIVITIES` collection, could have any number of documents, where each document could have any number of `Issue`.

In your case you only have 1 document and it has an array of `Issue`.

So, if you want to display all the `Issue` of the first document, you could do something like this:

```
return Column(
    children: snapshot.data.documents.first['Issue']
       .map<Widget>((issue) => buildItem(issue))
       .toList());
```

Then `buildItem()` would receive a `Map<String, dynamic>`, like this:

```
Card buildItem(Map issue) {
```

So now you could access to the map, like this:

```
issue['Help_Description']
```

If you want to show all issues from all documents, one below the other, in one single column, you could do something like this:

```
final issuesLists = snapshot.data.documents
    .map((doc) =>
        doc['Issue'].map<Widget>((issue) => buildItem(issue)).toList())
    .toList();
return Column(children: issuesLists.expand<Widget>((issues) => issues).toList());
```

Comment: It still outputs a null value sir @Pablo :(

Comment: I updated my answer. I couldn't test it but I think you could get the idea to make it work.

Comment: I tried it sir @Pablo but it showed me this, The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Card). and supposedly I need to get lots of documents that has an array of "Issue" not only 1 sir. Please help. I really need to fix this. Stuck here for how many days already :(

Comment: Sorry, is first['Issue'] not first['Issues'], check if changing that works.

Comment: Oh silly me, I got the spelling wrong here children snapshot.data.documents.first['Issue']. but now this appeared :( type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Comment: In my emulator screen it is showing me an error saying  type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<wigdet>' :(

Comment: Try changing .map( for .map<Widget>(

Comment: Yeeeeey that works ! thanks so much. But what if I have lots of documents to show sir @Pablo? and all of them has an array of Issue in it? How will I do it? sorry just a newbie in android :(

Comment: You want to show all issues from all documents, one below the other, in one single column?

Comment: Yes sir @Pablo, is it possible?

Comment: I updated my answer with that case, but I can't test it. Please, with all the information I gave you, you should be able to have an idea and try to make it work.

Comment: again it is showing me 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<wigdet>' sir @Pablo

Comment: It works sir @Pablo, you're a life savior. Thank you so much.

Comment: But its kinda not stable, if you go to another nav then go back to that nav where it shows the list of issue, it turns red first then shows the list. Any idea how to stable it sir @Pablo?

Comment: Ask another question for that specific problem and someone could help you.

Comment: Sir @pablo? Can I ask again a question here? I badly need help.

Comment: I want to do now is the same thing that you've given me here sir @pablo, but a bit different in getting the data. I want now is to get a specific document and output all of the issues. How can I do that sir? Please help. No one is replying on my post :(